# Do ghosts of Hogwarts eat?

Tags: harry-potter

I don't know if it is *necessary* for them to eat. But it makes me wonder why there is pudding in ***Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*** when Nearly Headless Nick invited Harry to his Deathday Party.

(Feel free to edit and include the chapter)

Comment: Come on when do ghosts ever eat.

Comment: Honestly, did you carefully read what I posted before you commented?

Comment: You mean the part about pudding being near ghosts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is in the pudding (ha!)

> “Without any supper?” said Snape, a triumphant smile flickering
>   across his gaunt face. “I didn’t think ghosts provided food fit for
>   living people at their parties.”

---

> “Now, Ron, the Sorting’s much more important than food,” said
>   Nearly Headless Nick as “Madley, Laura!” became a Hufflepuff.
>
> “ ’Course it is, if you’re dead,” snapped Ron.

Why is there food at Nick's deathday party?  Because it's a party.  However, the food is moldy and disgusting, not meant to be eaten by alive people.

> “Can you taste it if you walk through it?” Harry asked him.
>
> “Almost,” said the ghost sadly, and he drifted away.

Comment: Oh haha thanks btw. I didn't realize they just displayed those gross.

Comment: @BookStriker You're welcome.